# Convert String to List [Groovy]

Tags: groovy

I want to convert my string of the form `"aa, bb, cc"` to a List of the form `[aa, bb, cc]`.

There are questions *similar* to this but, there, the string looked like this: `"[aa, bb, cc]"`.

Hope someone knows a problem to my specific question.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: how about String[] stringArr = yourString.split(",").trim()?
of course you have to convert that array to a list with : ArrayList wordlist = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(stringArr))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
def myList = "aa, bb, cc".split(',') as List
```

Comment: just calling `.split(',')` will leave the spaces before ` bb` and ` cc` . With the groovy spread operator `.split(',')*.trim()` you can trim unwanted whitespaces on the split values.